# Is it thread-safe to iterate a HashMap object concurrently?

Tags: java, concurrency

If multiple threads **concurrently** iterate a `HashMap` object, *without modifying it*, is there a chance for race conditions?

Comment: Well obviously if nobody is modifying anything, there can't be any data race..

Comment: @Voo: I wouldn't say "obviously". It's true because the JDK is well-designed in this respect, but it's quite possible to design an API where seemingly read-only operations nonetheless involve internal temporary modifications that can't safely be done concurrently. (In fact, I've created such APIs myself, for various reasons.) So it's a legitimate question.

Comment: Do threads use the same iterator?

Comment: @pst: Actually, some of the XML API are not thread-safe even for multiple readers, as they keep an internal DOM iterator.

Comment: @ruakh In which case iterating through the collection modifies it, hence there's no contradiction to what I said :) Although yes it depends on the actual API, but I'd expect something like changes to the internal state by iterating through it to be documented, because that's really not the expected behavior for a collection.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk: Every `Iterator` on the `HashMap` is declared and allocated **locally**, on every thread's *stack*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No race, if you can guarantee that no other thread would modify this HashMap while it is being iterated.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, that is perfectly fine. As long as all reads are synchronized with all writes, and all writes are synchronized with each other, there is no harm in concurrent reads; so if there are no writes at all, then all concurrent access is safe.

Comment: You don't need synchronization if its not modified.

Answer (score 1):

It will be al right. But if any of the threads add or remove an item, this will throw exception in any other threads that are just iterating HashMap (any collection in fact)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to iterate of a Map repeatedly you may find it marginally faster to iterate over an array copy.

```
private final HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
private volatile Map.Entry<String, String>[] propertyEntries = null;

private void updatePropertyEntries() {
    propertyEntries = properties.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[properties.size()]);
}

{
    // no objects created
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : propertyEntries) {

    }
}
```

BTW: You can have one thread modify/replace the propertyEntries while iterating in many threads with this pattern.